# Windows API equivalent of Stopwatch::ElapsedTicks?

Tags: c#, winapi, timing

I am calling into an API that needs the elapsed ticks between 2 points. In a C# version, I use `Stopwatch` and utilize the `ElapsedTicks` method (this seems to be different than `ElapsedMilliseconds` obviously).

In Windows API I see `GetTickCount()`. However this seems to return the elapsed milliseconds, not ticks. How can I accomplish the equivalent with Windows API? (Prefer language agnostic since I might be writing a few wrappers for this).

Comment: Stopwatch is a wrap of the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` API. However see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12948899/1504523) and/or  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11537483/1504523) answer to get more details. GetTickCount wön't deliver satisfying results because of its platform dependent granularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopwatch uses [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) internally, if it's available.

It determines if it's available by calling [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx) - the return value is also used to determine the frequency of the performance counter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, on what platform(s) running a C#-compiled .NET managed executable is  it *not* available? CE?

Comment: Can I use GetTickCount and convert that into ticks by multiplying by the processor frequency or something?