# convert string "172406" to integers 17, 24, 06 fast

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to convert fast the string in format "HHmmss" to DateTime or integers. I've tested such code:

```
Console.WriteLine("decoding " + text);
long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
Console.WriteLine("start time " + microseconds);
field = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "HHmmss", null);
microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
Console.WriteLine("finish time " + microseconds);
```

and the output is

```
decoding 172400
start time 121
finish time 244

decoding 172400
start time 236
finish time 383

decoding 172400
start time 116
finish time 416

decoding 172400
start time 235
finish time 421

decoding 172359
start time 149
finish time 323
```

so in average about 150 microseconds. What's a lot of time, i'm writing HFT software and the best HFT has in average 10 microseconds "tick-to-trade" time (this includes everything!). I understand that using c# this is imposible however i still think that 150 microseconds is too much even using c#.

Now I want to use another algorithm, however I don't know how to "extract" integers from the text:

```
field = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, /*extract hour, min, sec from text*/)
```

What can you suggest and what would be the fastest way?
Please do not ask why I'm care about perfomance instead just suggest how to do that faster.

**Results:**

Using `DateTime.ParseExact(text, "HHmmss", null)` about 6-8 ticks

Using `TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(text, "hhmmss", null);` about 3-4 ticks

Using `int hour = 10 * text[0] + text[1] - 11 * '0';`... about 0 ticks

Acutally much less than 0 ticks if using loop for measurements. Actually it was found that last version is 100 times faster than other.

**Code:**

```
    long startMicroseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks /*/ (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L))*/;

    //TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(text, "hhmmss", null);

    //int hour = 10 * text[0] + text[1] - 11 * '0';
    //int minute = 10 * text[2] + text[3] - 11 * '0';
    //int second = 10 * text[4] + text[5] - 11 * '0';

    field = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "HHmmss", null);

    long finishMicroseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks /*/ (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L))*/;
    Console.WriteLine("elappsed " + (finishMicroseconds - startMicroseconds));
```

Comment: This is a bad way to time it. Run the code in a loop and time the entire loop. Then get the average time per iteration.

Comment: @MarkByers and the result would be 150 +- 50.

Comment: @javapowered: did you test that, or is it an assumption?

Comment: You're including the string concatenation of "start time " + microseconds and the call to Console.WriteLine in your calculation of how long it takes.

Comment: i didn't tested. i printed 20-30 outputs and compared that in average they are equal. i do not need to improve 150 microseconds to 140 microseconds. i need to improve 150 microseconds to 5 microseconds. that's why i don't need to spent my time to write extra code for true average calculations. i know it more that 100 and that's enough.

Comment: My performance test indicates that it takes 1.6μs. You really should improve your benchmarking code. I suspect the `Console.WriteLine`call is much more expensive than the format conversion.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That's more in line with my experiences...

Comment: @CodesInChaos right just discovered that almost everything is spent in console.WriteLine, i should really switch lines for perfomance.

Comment: @javapowered: You should just do what I suggested in the first place. Add a for loop around your code and a division where you calculate the time taken. That's all you need. You'll get a much more accurate result.

Comment: @MarkByers i don't need accurate result anymore as the fastest version already suggested in answers

Comment: I tested it on my 5yo Core 2 Duo laptop, Release build, using a `Stopwatch` around a 1,000,000 iterations loop, printing the result once after the loop. The `Timespan.ParseExact` method suggested by @Tim below takes ~500ns, while the optimized method by @MarkByers takes ~5ns (both tested 1,000,000 times in a loop). While 100 times faster, I doubt it will influence the entire running time of your program (unless you are strictly doing just this, converting billions of timestamps).

Comment: Could you post your test code if you get some spare time? I wonder why the difference is that large compared to my findings (I got a 100x difference between `TimeSpan` and plain arithmetic).

Comment: @Groo tick on my machine takes more than 500 ns. as I test only ONE iteration i can not measure 5 ns. Of course your test is much better and correct!

Comment: @javapowered: ok, two things then: 1. you should definitely put the test in a loop and then divide the time afterwards (this will get you the resolution you need), and 2. reading `Elapsed` without stopping the `Stopwatch` is not atomic (not guaranteed even on a 64-bit machine), so you should probably use `Start` and `Stop` around each test. I pasted my code [here](http://pastebin.com/V7mbVSWF), if you ever want to run it yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This approach doesn't use any string substring or parsing methods. It uses only indexing and simple arithmetic:

```
int hour   = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + s[1] - '0';
int minute = (s[2] - '0') * 10 + s[3] - '0';
int second = (s[4] - '0') * 10 + s[5] - '0';
```

This next version is probably even faster because the calculation has been partially evaulated to help the compiler. As a result it is slightly harder to read and understand:

```
int hour   = s[0] * 10 + s[1] - '0' * 11;
int minute = s[2] * 10 + s[3] - '0' * 11;
int second = s[4] * 10 + s[5] - '0' * 11;
```

For kicks you might also want to see if this is even faster, though I suspect that this code will be the same as the previous version:

```
int hour   = s[0] * 10 + s[1] - 528;
int minute = s[2] * 10 + s[3] - 528;
int second = s[4] * 10 + s[5] - 528;
```

Comment: +1, cause that's probably the best one can get in terms of performance. But I would be rather surprised if compiler wouldn't reduce all three versions to the last one.

Comment: there are two correct answers but i'm marking yours as it was answered 1 minute early :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want performance instead of readability you can work with raw chars directly:

```
hour   = 10*s[0] + s[1] - 11*'0';
minute = 10*s[2] + s[3] - 11*'0';
second = 10*s[4] + s[5] - 11*'0';
```

---

btw. `DateTime.Now` is quite slow because it needs to convert the current time to the local time-zone. You should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead. On my comp `DateTime.UtcNow` costs 9ns, `DateTime.Now` costs 900ns.

You also should fetch `DateTime.UtcNow` only once, else you get a race-condition.

Comment: shouldn't this be `-11*'0'`?

Comment: yes i do really want perfomance instead of readability, thanks will test

Comment: this takes less than 1 microsecond, i will test other options.

Comment: it takes 0 to 1 tick on my machine. so this one is really fast.

Answer (score 2):

Is this really too slow?

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("172406", "hhmmss", null);
int hh = ts.Hours;
int mm = ts.Minutes;
int ss = ts.Seconds;
```

It is at least easy to understand.

Comment: this is about 70 microseconds what is better but I still expect < 10 microseconds

Comment: I have measured 4 Ticks with Stopwatch. One microsecond are 1000 ticks.

Comment: @Tim: I think `Stopwatch.Ticks` depends on the OS and hardware. Can you translate that to milliseconds? And, did you test that in a larger loop, or only for a single pass?

Comment: @Groo: Yes, i've tested it in a loop (1000) iterations and divided through this number. Maybe that's also not an accurate way to measure it because it's somehow optimized out. In a single test it needs 500 ticks which is 0.5 microseconds [xeon dual core 2.26GHZ; Win2008].

Comment: i will retest. by accident I included `Console.Writeline` in my test

Comment: But regarding `Ticks`, on my system, for example, `Stopwatch.Ticks` equals to `1558623` (~1.5M ticks per second). So, it's usually safer to simply use `Stopwatch.Stop()` and then read the `Elapsed` or `ElapsedMilliseconds` property.

Comment: hm this takes 2-3 up to 10 microseconds on my machine

Comment: @Groo: Of course you should stop the stopwatch before you want to inspect the values.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't my point, I was mostly referring to the sentence: *One microsecond are 1000 ticks*, the value which I haven't yet met for a `Stopwatch` (maybe I haven't tested it on a xeon?).

Comment: retested once again, on my machine it takes 3-5 ticks. but i do not stop stopwatch

Comment: one microseconds it not 1000 ticks. even on same machine tick "length" can be changed. `Stopwatch.Frequency` property need to be used.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, I made a mistake, what I meant to say is: *"on my system, for example, **`Stopwatch.Frequency`** equals to 1558623 (~1.5M ticks per second)"*. That's why it's best not to use `Ticks`.

Comment: @javapowered: How do you change a readonly field? On my system the method from [**msdn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency(v=vs.100).aspx) outputs: _"Operations timed using the system's high-resolution performance counter.
  Timer frequency in ticks per second = 2208066
  Timer is accurate within 452 nanoseconds"_ But now i also remember why you cannot simply convert microsecond to ticks.

Comment: I think @javapowered wanted to say that the value could be changed by the OS while it's running, but I doubt that this is correct (it would be a mess). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12931733/69809) mentions that possibility.